# DynamoDB User managed usergroups

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-iam

I am fairly new to AWS and despite searching and reading about roles & policies. I still cannot figure out how I could go about having a user managed user groups to control access of items in DynamoDB tables. If someone could help me search by giving me the terminology or examples, I would greatly appreciate it.

Use Case Example :

- User1 creates the item "Group_A" in the table called "Groups".
- User2 creates the item "Group_B" in the table called "Groups".
- Another table called "Messages" has a sort key which can be any item
  of the table "Groups".

How can User1 give access to "Messages" of "Group_A" to User3 and User4 without allowing access to User2.

Comment: That really sounds like the type of thing you would control via your application, not directly in the database. Similar to how a typical webapp using a SQL database would have access to the entire DB and use some sort of authorization system built into the app to control who has access to what data.

Comment: Any idea how I could do this and avoid people possibly access data that they should not have access to?

Comment: Are you giving them access to run direct database queries? Are you giving them credentials to login to your AWS account? Generally an application does not give users direct database access, and authorization is handled in the application layer, not the database layer. You mentioned Java, so I would check out Spring Security.

Comment: I'm very grateful for the help Mark. I think I just have a very small understanding of how this all work. I made a userpool, the user has to authenticate and then get credentials to access the tables through a role that has a policy. Maybe I am being paranoid but my understanding was that unless I somehow block access to individual items with the policy itself, someone could just make an app to authenticate and get access to the whole table. I will check Spring Security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scenario is not directly achievable through IAM policy ( Which is attached to a User or Role) with DynamoDB Fine Grained Access Control that is connected with a Userpool.

DynamoDB at its finest access control level allows to allows row level access control by leading key. For example in your case, if the hashkey of the Message Item in Messages table is a property of logged in user in Cognito, its possible to grant only for that user with an IAM policy.

However the approach you can achieve this is in application level. For example you can setup an API Gateway and Lambda so that, at API Gateway the id_token issued by Cognito is verified and in Lambda Code you can write a query to restrict and retrieve data based on your access control list.

Comment: Thanks Ashan, I am looking into API gateway & Lambda at the moment and it really seem to be the way to go.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/